# Rails 4 not taking parameter list - error in console - actionView::Template::error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

**Update**:  *I had two issues in here - the one listed in the console had not matched the title I posted*. The issue with actionView::Template::error was in fact caused by the lack of pluralization - I gave answer for it to the most complete answer below - thank you!

**Original Question:**

I'm working with cocoon gemfile & following the ERB style of it without haml/slim.  I have my github here - The branch I'm working on is "cmodel" -[Link](https://github.com/Mirv/cocoontest). I got one of the errors taken care of myself - but this last one is just elusive - oddly too - I lost the field that normally shows the ingredient with the quantity - back on to the point...

My question is ... since when I search my repo on github for "ingredient_attributes" & see it only in my controller parameter's ... where is the error coming from & what would fix it?

"Unpermitted parameter: ingredient_attributes"

or

"Unpermitted parameter: ingredients" is coming from ... I managed to get this mostly working - this is the last element and I've been over a ton of files and stated pluralization etc, along with trying 3 or 4 formats for the accept_parameters_for & then the ingredient_attributes.

**My console output for the current error:**

```
Started GET "/recipes/1/edit" for 68.54.21.200 at 2015-12-21 02:53:27 +0000
Cannot render console from 68.54.21.200! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by RecipesController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Recipe Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Rendered recipes/_form.html.erb (8.2ms)
  Rendered recipes/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (9.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (No association found for name `ingredients'. Has it been defined yet?):
    30: 
    31:   <fieldset id="recipe-ingredients">
    32:     <ol>
    33:       <%= f.fields_for :quantities do |quantity| %>
    34:         <%= render 'quantity_fields', f: quantity %>
    35:       <% end %>
    36:     </ol>
  app/models/quantity.rb:6:in `<class:Quantity>'
  app/models/quantity.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  app/views/recipes/_form.html.erb:33:in `block in _app_views_recipes__form_html_erb___1490943344300843366_36721460'
  app/views/recipes/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_recipes__form_html_erb___1490943344300843366_36721460'
  app/views/recipes/edit.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_recipes_edit_html_erb___3608590124593016081_36957880'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (20.7ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (3.6ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (99.4ms)
```

**Setup**

- I ran the bundle install for the gemfile.
- I made the entry in assests/application.js for the "//= require cocoon". It's been compiled and raked.
- I setup a controller to view ingredient model directly and can add them manually through the ingredient page - but it never saves my ingredient via the Recipe model.

**Models:**

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quantities
  has_many :ingredient,
           :through => :quantities
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quantities,
           :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient
end

class Quantity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quantities
  has_many :recipes, through: :quantities
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quantities
end
```

**Controller:**

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_recipe, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /recipes/1/edit
  def edit
        @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /recipes
  # POST /recipes.json
  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.save
        format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @recipe }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /recipes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /recipes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.update(recipe_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @recipe }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_recipe
      @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def recipe_params
      #seems to work, but getting errors saving
      params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :description, :instruction, 
      quantities_attributes:  [:id, :amount, :ingredient, :_destroy], 
      ingredient_attributes:  [:id, :name, :_destroy],
      recipe_attributes:      [:title, :description, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

Here's the views ... portion from the github I linked above ...

**edit.html.erb**

```
<h1>Editing Recipe</h1>

    <%= render 'form' %>

    <%= link_to 'Show', @recipe %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', recipes_path %>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @recipe, html: {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
  <% if @recipe.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@recipe.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this recipe from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @recipe.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <fieldset id="recipe-meta">
    <ol>
      <li class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :title, "Recipe Name", class: "control-label" %>
        <div class="controls"><%= f.text_field :title %></div>
      </li>
      <li class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :description, "A brief description of this recipe", class: "control-label" %>
        <div class="controls"><%= f.text_area :description, rows: 5 %></div>
      </li>
      <li class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :instruction, "Instructions for this recipe", class: "control-label" %>
        <div class="controls"><%= f.text_area :instruction, rows: 10 %></div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="recipe-ingredients">
    <ol>
      <%= f.fields_for :quantities do |quantity| %>
        <%= render 'quantity_fields', f: quantity %>
      <% end %>
    </ol>
    <%= link_to_add_association 'add ingredient', f, :quantities, 'data-association-insertion-node' => "#recipe-ingredients ol", 'data-association-insertion-method' => "append", :wrap_object => Proc.new {|quantity| quantity.build_ingredient; quantity } %>
  </fieldset>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

_quantity_fields.html.erb

```
<li class="control-group nested-fields">
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.label :amount, "Amount:" %>
    <%= f.text_field :amount %>

    <%= f.fields_for :ingredient do |quantity_ingredient| %>
      <%= quantity_ingredient.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to_remove_association "remove", f %>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: this may not be the whole answer, but a couple of problems I see is 1. in Recipe class it should be "has_many ingredients" (note plural). 2. the error message says "no association found for the relation ingredients" this is correct. Quantity has the method ingredient (note singular, not plural). I don't think you've shown us where this error originates, it's in the one of the templates.

Comment: In your Recipe model it should be - `has_many :ingredients`. You have missed an 's'.

Comment: What is the status of this question? I see two errors: in your associations (as pointed out by others) and your strong parameters definition. The start of your question is somewhat confusing as to what is now/currently blocking you. The link to the github repo contains no relevant code.

Comment: Nathan!  I've got two of your demo's working so far - ty so much for them & the wonderful gem!!  This one I tried adapting & I made it is a mess.  My family is in town and I didn't get to hack away at this yesterday.  I feel like there's two separate errors currently - but the model has to be fixed first & I will post an update - I hope to sneak away for an hour to research this today before the holiday begins.

Comment: I put up a question for the second part of this ... I'm still plugging along by trial and error.  [New question of the same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457789/ruby-on-rails-4-missing-form-field-after-commit-error-is-unpermitted-paramet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an addition to `Praveen George`'s answer, you can debug Rails relatively simply if you follow what it says on screen (most of the time):

> No association found for name `ingredients'. Has it been defined yet?

This basically means that you don't have the `ingredients` association defined in the model you're calling.

As pointed out by `Praveen`, your problem resides in the `Recipe` model. You have to call the association by its pluralized name:

```
#app/models/recipe.rb
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :ingredients
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end
```

Comment: When I do pluralize it - the system won't load the page at all.  I feel like you are correct - it's just I'm so turned around from all the active record model examples showing the cross/pivot/join table owning the other tables  - I'm double checking everything I can lately.  I feel like it's better to fix the model, but this means I'm going to be rewriting the part of the code I understand the least - the cocoon portion & view probably.

Comment: When you say the page won't load at all - what happens? What does it say?

Comment: @rich : you are simply awesome :)

Comment: The page won't load.  I believe it's a template error - I do have a github link up.  I won't be able to test any of the answers until I get home.  I am still new to ruby - so I think I made a horrible mistake by trying to bend the model around the issues I was getting from the the view.

Comment: It should be okay - everyone starts somewhere; have you got your `github` link?

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in declaring association **class Recipe** with **has_many** relation.
try changing the relation to the following in your **Recipe model**

```
has_many :ingredients
```

Comment: The key here being the pluralization of the association name

Comment: @RichPeck : thank you man, dont know how to contact you, to let you know that http://www.frontlineutilities.co.uk/ is down, I was eager to see this, sorry to comment over here about it.

Comment: No problem buddy , we've had to change the server to another and are working on getting it back up :) Thanks for posting about it though - I upvoted your answer btw

Comment: @RichPeck : wow that sounds cool, let me know once its on air, Wish to see it, coz I admire your coding :)

Comment: This was the right path, but the other answer was just a touch more complete - thank you!

Comment: @RaptorMan : Its cool buddy, what matters is to solve your problem. Rich always maintains his integrity and easiness in understanding the problem and solution, lot more to learn from him.